# How to add a delay inside the Executor bound to CameraX's analyzer?

Tags: android, android-camerax

Inside my overridden `analyze()` I need to add some kind of throttle before performing an IO operation. Without the throttle, this operation gets executed immediately at each call of `analyze()` and it actually completes quickly, but apparently the calls are too fast and after a while the camera preview freezes for eternity (the app is still running because Logcat keeps displaying new messages).

I'm currently investigating if it has something to do with my code, like forgetting to call `imageProxy.close()`. So far everything seems fine and I'm afraid the device that performs the IO operation is raising too many interrupts for the CPU to handle, or something along the lines.

I've tried the good old `Thread.sleep()` but obviously it blocks the main thread and freezes the UI; I've seen some examples with `Handler#postDelayed()` but I don't think it does what I want; I've tried wrapping the IO call in a coroutine with a `delay()` at the beginning but again I don't think it does what I want. Basically I'd like to call some form of `sleep()` on the `Executor` thread itself, from within the code executed by it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> after a while the camera preview freezes for eternity

I've seen this issue occur many times, and it's usually due to an image that the `Analyzer` doesn't close. Are you seeing the issue even when the image analysis use case isn't used?

> I've tried the good old Thread.sleep() but obviously it blocks the main thread and freezes the UI

Why's that? This shouldn't be the case if you're adding the call to `Thread.sleep()` inside `Analyzer.analyze()`, since it'll block the thread of the `Executor` you provided when calling `ImageAnalysis.setAnalyzer()`, which shouldn't be tied to the main thread.

One option to perform analysis fewer times is to drop images inside the `Analyzer`, something like the following:

```
private static final int ANALYSIS_DELAY_MS = 1_000;
private static final int INVALID_TIME = -1;
private long lastAnalysisTime = INVALID_TIME;

public void analyze (ImageProxy image) {
  final long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

  // Drop frame if an image has been analyzed less than ANALYSIS_DELAY_MS ms ago
  if (lastAnalysisTime != INVALID_TIME && (now - lastAnalysisTime < ANALYSIS_DELAY_MS)) {
    image.close();
  }

  lastAnalysisTime = now;
  
  // Analyze image
  image.close();
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the real issue here was that I was trying to achieve too many things at the same time, resulting in a very messy code. It's very probable that in the midst of that mayhem something slipped off my attention and I couldn't figure out why. After starting over from scratch I've realized how to do certain things in a different (and probably better) way. However, props for the snippet of the time based delay because I will absolutely need it soon.

Comment: Would it affect using `elapsedRealtime` here instead of `uptimeMillis`?

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way, This is how I am doing it in a local project. So in my Image Analyzer, I am rebinding the camera using Handler#PostDelayed and this gives a small black screen in preview, but it won't process the next image that quickly.

My use case was that I had to continuously scan barcodes, but the scanning was too fast and it kept on scanning one code many times. So, I just needed 100ms wait. So this works out for me.

```
try {
    cameraProvider.unbindAll()
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
         cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
             this, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA, useCaseGroup.build())
    }, 100)
}
catch(exc: Exception) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
}
```